# Using lmfit of two Gaussians how to restrain the parameters of the second peak in dependence of the first?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curve-fitting, lmfit

In a multi-peak fitting I intend to constrain the solution space for the parameters of the second peak based on the values of the first one. Especially I want to have the amplitude parameter of the second one never to be larger than the amplitude of the first one.

I've read on the lmfit website about "Using Inequality Constraints" and I have the feeling it should be possible with this approach, but I do not quite understand it well it enough to make it work.

```py
import lmfit
GaussianA = lmfit.models.GaussianModel(prefix='A_')
pars = GaussianA.make_params()
GaussianB = lmfit.models.GaussianModel(prefix='B_')
pars.update(GaussianB.make_params())
pars['B_amplitude'].set(expr = 'A_amplitude')
```

This locks in the amplitude of B to the amplitude of A. 
However, how do I specify that the amplitude of B is at most `'A_amplitude'`?

This doesn't work (but it would be awesome if it were that easy) but maybe helps to demonstrate what I'd like to have): `pars['B_amplitude'].set(1,max='A_amplitude')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `min` and `max` values for a `lmfit.Parameter` are not dynamically calculated from the other variables, but must be real numerical values.  That is, something like

```
pars['B_amplitude'].set(1,max='A_amplitude') # Nope!
```

will not work.

What you need to do is follow the documentation for an inequality constraint (see https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/constraints.html#using-inequality-constraints).   That is, you can think of

```
 B_amplitude < A_amplitude
```

as

```
 B_amplitude = A_amplitude - delta_amplitude
```

with `delta_amplitude` being some variable value that must be positive.

That can be expressed as

```
GaussianA = lmfit.models.GaussianModel(prefix='A_')
pars = GaussianA.make_params()
GaussianB = lmfit.models.GaussianModel(prefix='B_')
pars.update(GaussianB.make_params())

pars.add('delta_amplitude', value=0.01, min=0, vary=True)
pars['B_amplitude'].set(expr = 'A_amplitude - delta_amplitude')
```

Now `delta_amplitude` is a variable that must be positive, and `B_amplitude` is no longer a freely varying parameter but is constrained by the values of `A_amplitude` and `delta_amplitude`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have extended the expression as per the lmfit documentation to `pars['B_amplitude'].set(expr = '(A_amplitude - delta_amplitude) if (A_amplitude - delta_amplitude)>= 0 else 0')` so that the B_amplitude is small than A but always positive.

Comment: I am really happy with the lmfit package btw. That being said, I think it would be a nice feature (request) if lmfit could deal with parameter based limits internally and make simple stuff like `pars['B_amplitude'].set(1,min=0,max='A_amplitude')` work out of the box.

Comment: Does anything speak against using delta_amplitude as a factor? Like `pars.add('delta_amplitude', value=0.01, min=0, max=1, vary=True)` and
`pars['B_amplitude'].set(expr = 'A_amplitude * delta_amplitude')`.

Comment: @MatthiasArras Writing it as a multiplying factor that is between  [0, 1] would be a fine approach and might give a more meaningful parameter in some cases.  Using a "ternary if" expression instead of explicit parameter bounds is probably less stable as the fit would see no change in the residual if `A_amplitude - delta_amplitude` actually got below 0, and so could get lost.  FWIW,   "bounds expressions" could not work with the current bounds implementation -- they are set up statically before the real fit begins. I can't think of how to do that well.  So: "maybe, but not anytime soon".

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a plot of your data, how noisy is it? I understood that you do 2 seperate fits but you have 2 peaks in your data. If your data is friendly you might be able to fit first one peak and then take the amplitude of it and fit the second one by setting [limits](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/constraints.html) for the amplitude. But maybe it's better to set a limit for the x position as you are talking of two different peaks.

How I solved this in a little hacky way (I assume your problem is that your fit does not converges):

- Find the highest peak (maximum) in data -> x1
- cut out the data in the environment of the peak (x1 +- 2 half power width, depending of the distance of your peaks and the heights of them)
- find the highest peak (maximum) in the new reduced data -> x2

Use a custom fit curve which is a sum of your two gauss curves. `f(x) = gauss1 + gauss2`, where `gauss(x, x1, width, amplitude, y_offset)` and `gauss = amplitude/width * e^(-(x-x1)^2/width) + y_offset`

Sorry, it's years ago that I did that and without lmfit, so I can't give you details on it.